# Is it possible to get single result in aggregate?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to get a single document on `db.collection.aggregate` like as in `db.collection.findOne`?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking for here. Specifically you should explain what you want to do. BTW the answer given so far is wrong for most cases.

Comment: Did you try aggregate([....]).toArray()[0].total ?

Comment: aggregate([...]).toArray().then((data) => data[0]) works for me

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is possible to add [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage to aggregation pipeline. But even if it will match only one single document, then result will still be a list (of length one in that case). So the answer is "**NO**, it is not possible".

Answer (score 47):

Yes, it is possible. Just add a [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage with `_id` equal to `null`. That will calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole. E.g.

```
{ $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$price" }}}
```

Or if you want to get only one document from aggregated results, you can use [`$limit`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/):

```
{ $limit: 1 }
```

UPDATE: Both these solutions return *cursor* which would have single document. But don't think about `findOne` as something special. It also retrieves cursor and just gets first document (if any). Here is mongo shell implementation of `findOne`:

```
function ( query , fields, options ){
    var cursor = this.find(query, fields, -1 /* limit */, 0 /* skip*/,
        0 /* batchSize */, options);

    if ( ! cursor.hasNext() )
        return null;
    var ret = cursor.next();
    if ( cursor.hasNext() ) throw "findOne has more than 1 result!";
    if ( ret.$err )
        throw "error " + tojson( ret );
    return ret;
}
```

As you can see, it internally uses `find`. So, if you want to get single document instead of cursor with single document, you can write your own function which does same with `aggregate`. E.g.

```
> DBCollection.prototype.aggregateOne = function(pipeline) {
     var cur = this.aggregate(pipeline);
     if (!cur.hasNext())
         return null; 
     return cur.next(); 
 }
```

Usage:

```
> db.collection.aggregateOne(...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get an array with one element

Comment: Bullseye (y), very nicely explained.

Answer (score 3):

yes it is possible. you need to use mongodb [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operation

ex: this is worked for me.

```
{ $lookup: { from: 'user', localField: 'userId', foreignField: 'id', as: 'publisherDetails' } },
{ $match: { id } }
```

mondodb [doc's](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) example:

```
db.articles.aggregate(
[ { $match : { id : "132ada123aweae1321awew12" } },
  { $lookup: { from: 'user', localField: 'userId', foreignField: 'id', as: 'publisherDetails' } } ]
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If *"by a single result"* you mean a `findOne` style return type, it should be impossible to do so. While not saying that it is impossible, it should be and should be treated as such. Aggregate operations are [documented](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to return [aggregate cursors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/) only, so the only robust conclusion to an aggregate operation should be either an `aggregate cursor` or an `error`. When you receive your aggregate cursor, you can then use its exposed methods to access your single document. To expect anything else is akin to courting chaos.

Ps: *Arrived massively late to this thread. Hope to help others who might end up here later on.*

Answer (score 1):

Just to improve the answer with another simple solution, and to avoid writing a lot of repeated code, this is my solution based on @Sergey Berezovskiy answer's.

```
import { Collection } from 'mongodb';

Collection.prototype.aggregateOne = async function(pipeline, options) {
   const items = await this.aggregate(pipeline, options).toArray();
   return items.length > 0 ? items[0] : null; 
}
```

And just like normal Aggregate function you can use like this:

```
return db.articles.aggregateOne(
   [ { $match : { id : "132ada123aweae1321awew12" } },
   { $lookup: { from: 'user', localField: 'userId', foreignField: 'id', as: 'publisherDetails' } } ]
);
```

And this will return the first document if exist or null.

Hope this will facilitate life of someone rsrs.

Comment: Why not just do this?

`const item = await this.aggregate(pipeline, options).toArray()[0] || null;`

Answer (score 0):

In Python you could convert the result to a list and get the first element:

```
result = list(mongo.db.collection.aggregate([{"$sample": {"size": 1}}]))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I actually go this to work was `collection.aggregate(pipeline).next()`

For me that was exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

**YES, you can do it**

***Easiest way*** => Example searching by id and retrieving one single element:

```
const getOne = async (id) => {
    const query = {_id: new ObjectId(id)};
    let arrayCursor = await collection.aggregate([
        {$match: query},
        ...
    ]);
    if (!arrayCursor.hasNext())
        return null;
    aSingleElement = await arrayCursor.next();
    return aSingleElement
}
```

---

**Extra information in case that you want more details:**

- Aggregate function return a cursor.
- It's better getting a single object moving thought cursors, and not converting toArray, manage as an array and get first element.
- This option is useful in cases that you wanna profit some options from aggregate function, like for example $lookup for doing joins and other options
- You can extract the function, to be able to use it everywhere in the project with other aggregate functions. In case that you don't know how to do it, let me know to give you more info about.
- The idea is to check if the cursor has an element, and in that case, move to the first element and retrieve it as a result.