# How to get $match result in single document and not in array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the a topic collection like so

```
 {
    "_id": "1",
    "topic_name": "Animation",
},
 {
    "_id": "2",
    "topic_name": "Animation"
}
```

and when I use

```
    db.topic.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: 1 }
  }
```

I get the result in array

```
[
{
    "_id": "1",
    "topic_name": "Animation"
}
]
```

My question is: is it possible to get the result in single document and not in array with $match? I don't want to use findOne method because I still need to create one more pipeline with aggregate. My expected result would be

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "topic_name": "Animation"
}
```

Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: Checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375301/is-it-possible-to-get-single-result-in-aggregate It might give you your answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get single result in aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375301/is-it-possible-to-get-single-result-in-aggregate)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get the result in single doc because `$match` will always give a list of docs.

you can use `find` instead of `aggregate` then you get the single doc.