# "Inner join" like with MongoDB in Flask, Jinja

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-pymongo

I'm trying to perform an 'inner join' *like* with two MongoDB collections using Flask.

I think I should be using `$lookup` to achieve this, and my route currently is:

```
@app.route("/perfumes")
def perfumes():
    perfumes = mongo.db.perfumes.find()
    users = mongo.db.perfumes.aggregate(
        [
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "mongo.db.users",
                    "localField": "author",
                    "foreignField": "username",
                    "as": "creator",
            }
        }
    ]
)
return render_template("perfumes.html", title="Perfumes", perfumes=perfumes, users=users)
```

In my template I'm iterating through the `perfumes` in one collection and would like to access all the data in the `users` collection, as each perfume item has been created by one user.
The `perfumes` collection has an `author` field which should be used to link the `username` field in the `users` collection.
A very simplified (stripped down) version of my template looks like this:

```
% for perfume in perfumes %}
    {{ perfume.name }}
    Created by {{ <HERE I WANT TO HAVE MY ITEM CREATOR> }} on {{ perfume.date_updated.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}
{% endfor %}
```

What am I missing in order to have this '*join*' working and be able to access to all data for that item from both collections?

Thank you!!

NOTE: I want to access more than just the creator's username, like profile picture, etc, that's why I need the join.

UPDATE: These are the structures I'm using for both databases:

```
{
    "perfumes": {
        "author": "<string>",
        "brand": "<string>",
        "name": "<string>",
        "descritpion": "<text field>",
        "date_updated": "<date>",
        "public": "<boolean>",
        "picture": "<string>"
    },
    "users": {
        "username": "<string>",
        "first_name": "<string>",
        "last_name": "<string>",
        "email": "<string>",
        "is_admin": "<boolean>",
        "avatar": "<string>"
    }
}
```

So the `author` in `perfumes` would be linkable with the `username` in `users`.

Comment: Could you post how you collection looks, few documents and your expected output?

Comment: I just updated my question. So basically I'd like to access each item in my template, and access all the data from its author, which links to the `username` in `users`. `Username` is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a simple aggregation. Try the below code:

```py
cur = mongo.db.perfumes.aggregate(
    [
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'users', # You can directly specify on which collection you want to lookup
                'localField': 'author',
                'foreignField': 'username',
                'as': 'creator',
            }
        },
        {
            '$unwind' : '$creator'
        },
        {
            '$project': {
                'username' : '$creator.username',
                'perfumeName' : '$name',
                'date_updated' : '$date_updated',
                'profilePicture' : '$creator.avatar',
                ..., # Rest of the items that you want to display
                '_id': 0
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Return the results like below:

```py
return render_template("perfumes.html", title="Perfumes", perfumes=cur) # You don't need to pass users
```

Display in the template like below:

```py
{% for perfume in perfumes %}
    {{ perfume['perfumeName'] }}
    Created by {{ perfume['username'] }} on {{ perfume['date_updated'].strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is wonderful! It just works beautifully! Exactly what I needed. I'm so grateful!

Comment: Just an additional question: Say I have a 3rd collection (types) for the types of perfume. How can I also 'join' that one on perfumes.type field so I have all 3 available in the template?

Comment: How can I pass (to another template) just ONE record of that cursor? What's the method to find one in the aggregate? I'm looking to display again all crossed information of a single record (no iteration involved)

Comment: For joining a 3rd collection, you should use a `$lookup` operator again. You can understand it from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813854/how-to-join-multiple-collections-with-lookup-in-mongodb. If you need any further help, you can post a separate question and let me know.

Comment: To find one in aggregation, you should use the `$match` operator on your unique field/primary key. But this will also result in a list of documents, but with length of one.

Comment: You can have a look this this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375301/is-it-possible-to-get-single-result-in-aggregate

Comment: Dear helper! I posted a new question explaining what I need to achieve with aggregating a third collection. Could you please help me? I'd be extremely grateful!.
Here's the new post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801980/aggregating-3-mongodb-collections-python-flask-jinja

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jinja filter in order to join the information from the two cursors, and then iterate over it on jinja as if it was a list o dicts.

Start creating a custom jinja filter, where aggregated cursor is the output from your `mongo.db.perfumes.aggregate` line: e.g. page_filters.py file

```
from .. import app

@app.template_filter()
def get_user_information(perfume_cursor):
    """ Creates a generator to get extra info of user """
    # Transform mongo cursor into a list of dicts
    perfume_cursor = list(perfume_cursor)

    for item in perfume_cursor:
        extra_info = mongo.db.users.find_one({"username": item['author']}, {"first_name": 1, "profile_picture": 1})
        # Declare below your desired user info
        item['user_info'] = dict(first_name=extra_info.first_name,profile_picture=extra_info.profile_picture)
        yield item
```

To make our filter available in the templates, we just need to import it in our top-level init.py

```
# Make sure app has been initialized first to prevent circular imports.
from .util import page_filters
```

Now on jinja, just use the filter

```
{% for perfume in (perfumes | get_user_information) %}
    {{ perfume['name'] }}
    Created by {{ perfume['user_info']['first_name']}} on {{ perfume['date_updated'].strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}
{% endfor %}
```

You should make the query more specific getting only the necassary user fields though, otherwise there might be too much info on your memory. The reason we use Generator, is to provide a means of processing data without loading the entire data-source into memory first.

refs:
https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/explore-flask/chapter-8/custom-filters
https://www.lachlaneagling.com/reducing-memory-consumption-python/

Comment: I'm trying this next, so, so many thanks for this! Amazed at the kindness and expertise found here!