# Aggregating 3 MongoDB collections - (Python, Flask, Jinja)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Thanks to great help found here I managed to put in place some aggregation for 2 collections in MongoDB.

```
@app.route("/perfume/<id>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def perfume(id):
    perfume = mongo.db.perfumes.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    form = AddReviewForm()
    cur = mongo.db.perfumes.aggregate(
        [
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "users",
                    "localField": "author",
                    "foreignField": "username",
                    "as": "creator",
                }
            },
            {"$unwind": "$creator"},
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "perfumeName": "$name",
                    "perfumeBrand": "$brand",
                    "perfumeDescription": "$description",
                    "date_updated": "$date_updated",
                    "perfumePicture": "$picture",
                    "isPublic": "$public",
                    "perfumeType": "$perfume_type",
                    "username": "$creator.username",
                    "firstName": "$creator.first_name",
                    "lastName": "$creator.last_name",
                    "profilePicture": "$creator.avatar",
                }
            },
            {"$match": {"_id": ObjectId(id)}},
        ]
    )
    return render_template(
        "perfume.html", title="Perfumes", cursor=cur, perfume=perfume, form=form
    )
```

I now would like to add a third collection to that aggregate.

My goal is the following: I have now 3 collections, `perfumes`, `users` and `reviews` and I want to display in a template a perfume (a document from the perfumes collection), data from the creator (which is a document in the users collection) and data from the review (a document from the reviews collection).

**I'm currently managing to do the first two**, but I'm adding the 'review perfume' functionality now.

Since reviewers are also users, I would like to aggregate this new collection to the current lookup.

This collection (reviews) has only 3 fields: `_id`, `review_author` and `review`. The `review_author` will necessarily be present in the users collection, since they have to be logged in to review.

I also managed to insert the `_id` of the review document (from the `reviews` collection) as an array element in the `perfumes` collection.
How's the new aggregate `lookup` I need in order to have in the template data from all three collections?
I'd be so happy to read help!

Currently my schemas are as follow:

```
{
    "perfumes": {
        "_id": "_id",
        "author": "<string>",  <== used to unwind with following collection
        "brand": "<string>",
        "name": "<string>",
        "perfume_type": "<string>",
        "description": "<text field>",
        "date_updated": "<date>",
        "public": "<boolean>",
        "picture": "<string>",
        "review": "<array>"
    },
    "users": {
        "_id": "_id",
        "username": "<string>",  <== used to unwind to previous coll, needs to link to next
        "first_name": "<string>",
        "last_name": "<string>",
        "email": "<string>",
        "is_admin": "<boolean>",
        "avatar": "<string>"
    },
    "reviews": {
        "_id": "_id",
        "review_author": "<string>", <== to be used as a link
        "review": "<text field>"
    },
}
```

Thank you!

UPDATE:

This is a sample document from `perfumes`

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5ebd751e0a52cd0dade39491"
        },
        "author": "Guillermo",
        "brand": "A new Brand",
        "name": "A new Perfume",
        "perfume_type": "Oriental",
        "description": "<p>This is the description</p>",
        "date_updated": {
            "$date": "2020-05-14T16:43:10.801Z"
        },
        "public": false,
        "picture": "generic.png",
        "review": [
            {
                "$oid": "5ebd752c0a52cd0dade39492"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is a sample document from `users`:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5eb09b0a7b62cdd2e8800d96"
        },
        "username": "Guillermo",
        "first_name": "Guillermo",
        "last_name": "Brachetta",
        "email": "brachetta@me.com",
        "password": "pbkdf2:sha256:150000$4vanQ3Qe$83031f081327e26c1125b861054f1d184bdb4373af323e6a10602587f6d40607",
        "is_admin": true,
        "avatar": "a92de23ae01cdfde.jpg"
    }
]
```

And this is a sample document from `reviews`:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5ebd752c0a52cd0dade39492"
        },
        "review_author": "Guillermo",
        "review": "<p>This is one review</p>"
    }
]
```

So one user can create many perfumes. A perfume can have many reviews.
Different users can create reviews for the same or different perfumes.

UPDATE 2:

This is looking very promising and I'm super excited about it!
I'll make a short schema of what I'm aiming to do in the template:

```
{% for item in cursor &}
  <perfume name>
  <perfume brand>
  <perfume description>
  <perfume picture>
  <author username (of the perfume)>
  <author first and last names>
  <date created>
  <eventually other information>
{% if current_user == author %}
  <button edit>
  <button delete>
{% endif %}
  <button review <=+ available to all logged in users>
{% endfor %}

{% for item in cursor['review'] <= this is not working %}
  <perfume review>
  <perfume review author>
  <perfume review author avatar>
  <eventually other information>
{% endfor %}
```

With the double aggregation I was achieving all of it except obviously the looping over the reviews.
Looking forward, I'm sure this is getting somewhere!! :)
P.S.: This is just very schematic to try to be clear with the idea!

Comment: Could you provide few sample documents from each of the collections which are related?

Comment: Done, looking forward!! Thank you!

Comment: I think `username` in `users` collection should be 'Guillermo'. The `review_author` can be other than the creator of the perfume?

Comment: yes, I had taken the wrong user. I updated it now. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: and yes, any user can review the perfumes, not necessarily the author. And perfumes can have many reviews (by one or different users).

Comment: When I was storing this collection in my system I was getting an error: ''$oid is not valid for storage." So, I stored the `_id` as `ObjectId` and then used for finding the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```py
cur = db.perfumes.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'users',
            'localField': 'author',
            'foreignField': 'username',
            'as': 'creator'
        }
    },
    {
        '$unwind': '$creator'
    },
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$review',
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'review',
            'let': {'rid': {'$toString': '$review._id'}},
            'pipeline': [{
                '$match': {
                    '$expr': {
                        '$eq': ['$$rid', {'$toString': '$_id'}]
                    }
                }
            }],
            'as': 'userReviews'
        }
    },
    {
        '$unwind': '$userReviews'
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'users',
            'localField': 'userReviews.review_author',
            'foreignField': 'username',
            'as': 'reviewUserInfo'
        }
    },
    {
        '$unwind': '$reviewUserInfo'
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id':'$_id',
            'perfumeName': {'$first': '$name'},
            'perfumeBrand': {'$first': '$brand'},
            'perfumeDescription': {'$first': '$description'},
            'date_updated': {'$first': '$date_updated'},
            'perfumePicture': {'$first': '$picture'},
            'isPublic': {'$first': '$public'},
            'perfumeType': {'$first': '$perfume_type'},
            'username': {'$first': '$creator.username'},
            'firstName': {'$first': '$creator.first_name'},
            'lastName': {'$first': '$creator.last_name'},
            'profilePicture': {'$first': '$creator.avatar'},
            'userReviews': {
                '$push': {
                    'reviewId': '$userReviews._id',
                    'review_author': '$userReviews.review_author',
                    'review': '$userReviews.review',
                    'review_author_first_name': '$reviewUserInfo.first_name',
                    'review_author_last_name': '$reviewUserInfo.last_name',
                    'review_author_email': '$reviewUserInfo.email',
                    'review_author_avatar': '$reviewUserInfo.avatar'
                }
            }
        }
    },
])
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ebd7eec93256dc00c8f6f6c"),
    "perfumeName" : "A new Perfume",
    "perfumeBrand" : "A new Brand",
    "perfumeDescription" : "<p>This is the description</p>",
    "date_updated" : {
            "$date" : "2020-05-14T16:43:10.801Z"
    },
    "perfumePicture" : "generic.png",
    "isPublic" : false,
    "perfumeType" : "Oriental",
    "username" : "Guillermo",
    "firstName" : "Guillermo",
    "lastName" : "Brachetta",
    "profilePicture" : null,
    "userReviews" : [
        {
            "reviewId" : ObjectId("5ebd752c0a52cd0dade39492"),
            "review_author" : "Guillermo",
            "review" : "<p>This is one review</p>",
            "review_author_first_name" : "Guillermo",
            "review_author_last_name" : "Brachetta",
            "review_author_email" : "brachetta@me.com",
            "review_author_avatar" : "a92de23ae01cdfde.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

**P.S.** - You can use `$match` operator to match a particular user, as you have done in OP and you can use `$project` operator to project more fields and get the required output.

Comment: Wow I would have never come up with something this complex! Amazing! Let me see how to implement this, because it's not working out of the box.
Using it 'as is' loops through the cursor and I get as many authors for the perfume as reviews there are. Maybe I'm not using my template well? Or I need to adapt the cursor?
I just updated the question hoping I'm more clear.
Amazing, and so many thanks! I hope you can help me with the final touch!!

Comment: Or maybe I'm just missing how to match just the creator of the perfume? I'm confused, haha!

Comment: I could also send you both my route and the template somewhere if you think this could make it easier?

Comment: I'm really struggling to get the result. I know this is so close, but I'm failing. I hope you could give me the last help I need :)

Comment: Hey buddy, chill, we are here to help you. And yesterday, I was running behind my sleep schedule, so I couldn't look into it. But, I am always happy to help. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and patience! I really appreciate it!
This cursor seems to be empty and I cannot get anything from it.
But maybe a compromise would be to use a lookup with perfumes and reviews only and leave users out of it. (I realised I can also insert user's records with current_user.username, current_user.avatar, etc) so perhaps it's not needed in the aggregate. Do you think that would make it simpler?

Comment: And so sorry if I sounded impatient! :) I'm just a beginner here and this is becoming an obsession, which I love!
Thanks so very much for all your help!

Comment: If you do the `lookup` with `perfumes` and `reviews`, then you wont fetch creator's and reviewer's details like `firstName`,`lastName`, `email` etc..

Comment: I thought: since the reviewer has to be logged in to post a review, I can push to the review `current_user.username`, `current_user.avatar`, etc. That would make possible to access the reviewer data without aggregating it, no?

Comment: But, what about the reviewer's data, who have not logged in?

Comment: Well, in order to post a review you have to be logged in. Otherwise the review route is not available

Comment: What do you mean by `push to the review`? Could you clarify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213920/discussion-between-ngshravil-py-and-guillermo-brachetta).

Comment: Of course. I'm inserting the reviewer (and review) information like this:

        ```mongo.db.reviews.insert(
            {
                "review_author": current_user.username,
                "review": form.review.data,
                "review_date": datetime.utcnow(),
                "review_avatar": current_user.avatar,
            }
        )```

So, since the reviewer is logged in, I can record (and later access) their information.